# Moving directories for portable git configuration

Tags: windows, git, github, git-config

I have installed the portable git version on my flash drive, but I don't want my repository to be in the same directory as the program. I can get to the directory using:

```
$ git -- git-dir=../Gits --work-tree=..Gits
```

But I don't want to enter that every time. So I found in [this article](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) on the `gitconfig` file. But it only shows how to set the `core.worktree`

> core.worktree
>
> Set the path to the root of the work tree. This can be overridden by
>   the GIT_WORK_TREE environment variable
>   and the --work-tree command line
>   option. It can be an absolute path or
>   a relative path to the .git directory,
>   either specified by --git-dir or
>   GIT_DIR, or automatically discovered.
>   If --git-dir or GIT_DIR are specified
>   but none of --work-tree, GIT_WORK_TREE
>   and core.worktree is specified, the
>   current working directory is regarded
>   as the root of the work tree.
>
> Note that this variable is honored even when set in a configuration file
>   in a ".git" subdirectory of a
>   directory, and its value differs from
>   the latter directory (e.g.
>   "/path/to/.git/config" has
>   core.worktree set to
>   "/different/path"), which is most
>   likely a misconfiguration. Running git
>   commands in "/path/to" directory will
>   still use "/different/path" as the
>   root of the work tree and can cause
>   great confusion to the users.

I have tried these settings to no avail.

```
[core]
  worktree = ../Gits
  gitdir = ../Gits
```

Does anyone know a way to set the `git-dir` and `work-tree` directories for [PortableGit-1.7.0.2-preview20100309.7z](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) for Windows so I don't have to type that in all the time?

Also is there a way to add the passphrase so I don't have to type that in either? I saw [these instructions](http://help.github.com/working-with-key-passphrases/), but the portable version apparently doesn't have a `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would any git repo in the same directory than your portable installation?

As long as your `%PATH%` reference your portable `Git/cmd` directory, you can just type '`git whatever`' in your Git repo anywhere, and the working directory and git directory will be at their default places.

And any Git version has access to `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`: open a `Git bashrc`, and type `cd`, then `pwd`: the path displayed is your '`~`'.
Then, if you have no `.profile` or `.bashrc` yet, create one, put it it a simple echo (`echo .profile` in the `.profile` file, '`echo .bashrc`' in the `.bashrc`), open another Git bashrc and check if your `.profile`/`.bashrc` are activated.

Comment: Ahhh ok, I see now, I got the directory situation worked out thanks! And I found that my `~` is located in my `c:\Documents and Settings\[user]` directory. So if I take my flash drive to a friend's machine, I won't have these settings? Is there any way to point the `~` to my flash drive?

Comment: @fudgey: maybe (not tested) by setting explicitly a `HOME` environment variable to the right path before opening any Git bash.

Comment: LOL Sorry, I have no clue when it comes to batch file programming, but you've answered my initial questions so I'll give you credit and worry about using the flash drive later :)

Comment: Worked like a charm. This way I figured that `.bashrc` was activated in PortableGit embedded with Fork git client. Then I could set the environment variable `LC_ALL` writing in that file `export LC_ALL=es_ES`

Comment: @RafaelPalomino Well done (I forgot about this ten-years old answer)